# Issues With Amdgpu after Upgrade

Tags: 22.04, amdgpu, firmware

GPU - Vega 8 Ryzen 3 2200g

I am having issues with some applications due to amdgpu driver issues. This seems to have resulted from a distribution update.

```
Log Dist-Update

Setting up libmagic-mgc (1:5.41-3) ...
Setting up libkf5solid5-data (5.92.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libkf5bookmarks-data (5.92.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libgsm1:amd64 (1.0.19-1) ...
Setting up anacron (2.3-31ubuntu2) ...
Setting up linux-firmware (20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.3) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-52-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/vangogh_gpu_info.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_mes.bin for module amdgpu
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-51-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/vangogh_gpu_info.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_mes.bin for module amdgpu
Setting up libvisual-0.4-0:amd64 (0.4.0-17build2) ...
Setting up libvisual-0.4-0:i386 (0.4.0-17build2) ...
Setting up psmisc (23.4-2build3) ...
Setting up breeze-cursor-theme (4:5.24.4-0ubuntu1) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/X11/cursors/Breeze_Snow.theme ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/X11/cursors/breeze_cursors.theme ...
Setting up libkf5khtml-data (5.92.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libkf5kdelibs4support-data (5.92.0-0ub

Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-43-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-52-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-52-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-51-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-51-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
Setting up kubuntu-desktop (1.418) ...
Processing triggers for dictionaries-common (1.28.14) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.20-2ubuntu4) ...
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20211016) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...

done.
done.
Processing triggers for libvlc
```

Comment: What kernel are you on? This started happening when I upgraded from kernel 5.13 > 6.0.

Comment: What are the issues? All you posted was a warning message which is to be expected when the kernel is newer than the firmware package. Installing the latest firmwares should fix those warnings. It's possible Ubuntu team didn't package them correctly and will fix itself in the future. But what exact problems are you having?